# Make some colorful tiles on click opens a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

I want to make some colorful tiles which on click open a modal with some more tiles. these tiles should refresh the modal and show another tiles.

I want to make a folder like thing in which there are more folder and some more folders.

Just tell me how to make it for one level deep, and I will do rest.

For now all I had done is this:

```css
html, body, .container
{
height: 100%; 
min-height: 100%;
}

.first {
float: left;
width: 20%;
height: 30%;
background-color: red;
}

.second{
float: left;
width: 20%;
height: 70%;
background-color: green;
}


.third{
float: right;
width: 80%;
height: 80%;
background-color: blue;
}

.fourth {
float: right;
width: 40%;
height: 20%;
background-color: #DDDDDD;
}

.last{
float: right;
width: 40%;
height: 20%;
background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="first">first</div><div class="third">third</div>
 <div class="second">second</div><div class="fourth">fourth</div>
 <div class="last">last</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Have you written any javascript for this?

Comment: naah! i didn't but plz help me... i m having a dead line

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably best to use something like Bootstrap (which is also going to require jQuery):

https://jsfiddle.net/ryanpcmcquen/jpe70pLy/

```css
html,
body,
.container {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.first {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  height: 30%;
  background-color: red;
}

.second {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  height: 70%;
  background-color: green;
}

.third {
  float: right;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.fourth {
  float: right;
  width: 40%;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
}

.last {
  float: right;
  width: 40%;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="first" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    first
  </div>
  <div class="third">third</div>
  <div class="second">second</div>
  <div class="fourth">fourth</div>
  <div class="last">last</div>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      Put a bunch of tiles here.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

That will handle the JavaScript for you and then you can just write some clean modal markup. More details here on how to use Bootstrap modals:

https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#live-demo

Comment: thanks, it worked and plz can you upvote this question, it is already graving my reputation. thanks for your help